# Windows' Powershell not sending and receiving packages

Tags: windows, powershell, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just got this PC with Windows 10 installed on it. I downloaded and installed WSL, but it does not send or receive packages.
I tried `ping google.com`, it fails; so does `wget`, and `sudo apt install zsh`. I also downloaded and installed Virtual Studio Code, tried running `pip install flask`. It also fails.

I learnt somewhere that other terminals copies Window's Powershell settings, which I don't doubt cause that one does not send or receive any data.
One of the codes I ran

```
PS C:\Users\user> Test-NetConnection google.com

WARNING: Name resolution of google.com failed


ComputerName   : google.com
RemoteAddress  :
InterfaceAlias :
SourceAddress  :
PingSucceeded  : False
```

```
PS C:\Users\user> ping 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

This one returns 200, but does not download the file

```
PS C:\Users\user> wget https://cdn.cs50.net/web/2020/spring/projects/1/wiki.zip


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {80, 75, 3, 4...}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    x-amz-version-id: null
                    X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
                    X-Amz-Cf-Pop: LHR62-C5
                    X-Amz-Cf-Id: F3GA_011PxvYpfjic4Xocx2f41myyRz3_S2nOVKGnQfLCitxtPNWXg==
                    Accept-Ra...
Headers           : {[Connection, keep-alive], [x-amz-version-id, null], [X-Cache, Miss from cloudfront], [X-Amz-Cf-Pop, LHR62-C5]...}
RawContentLength  : 10566
```

This also returns 200, but does not download the zip file

```
PS C:\Users\user> curl https://cdn.cs50.net/web/2020/spring/projects/0/search.zip


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {80, 75, 3, 4...}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    x-amz-version-id: null
                    X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
                    X-Amz-Cf-Pop: LHR62-C1
                    X-Amz-Cf-Id: uApA39xf_ejPnocw6fMkmCFondJ46_0m-Yv-Ew_2-4XM6SZ6dzD0fA==
                    Age: 38439...
Headers           : {[Connection, keep-alive], [x-amz-version-id, null], [X-Cache, Hit from cloudfront], [X-Amz-Cf-Pop, LHR62-C1]...}
RawContentLength  : 347
```

I have turned off Windows FIrewall, yet it still wouldn't work.